# How to process n number of rows in a pyspark dataframe or RDD

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Any spark kings out there?

Use Case: I have a dataframe of 1 Million rows, I want to process 5 rows in json at a time without loosing parallelism.

Example dataframe (df):

```
+-------------+---------+
|    col_a    |  col_b  |
+-------------+---------+
| row1a       | row1b   |
| row2a       | row2b   |
| row3a       | row3b   |
| row4a       | row4b   |
| row5a       | row5b   |
| row6a       | row6b   |
| row7a       | row7b   |
| ..          | ..      |
+-------------+---------+
```

Current working solution

zipwithindex

```
row_id_df = df.rdd.map(lambda x: json.dumps(x.asDict())).zipWithIndex().toDF(["item", "id"])
```

Above line will convert the dataframe to

dataframe(row_id_df):

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+
|                    item              |   id   |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| {"col_a": "row1a", "col_b": "row1b"} |   0    |
| {"col_a": "row2a", "col_b": "row2b"} |   1    |
| {"col_a": "row3a", "col_b": "row3b"} |   2    |
| {"col_a": "row4a", "col_b": "row4b"} |   3    |
| {"col_a": "row5a", "col_b": "row5b"} |   4    |
| {"col_a": "row6a", "col_b": "row6b"} |   5    |
| {"col_a": "row7a", "col_b": "row7b"} |   6    |
| ..                                   | ..     |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

As of now, I have all the rows with the id, now I do a groupby using expression which will group every 5 items to a group.

```
splitBy = (floor(col("id") / lit(5)) * lit(5)) \
                   .cast(IntegerType()).alias("id")

row_id_df.groupBy(splitBy) \
            .agg(collect_list(col("item"))) \
            .select(col("collect_list(item)").alias("items")) \
            .rdd.foreach(process_each_5)

process_each_5(data):
    print(len(data.items)) // 5
```

I was able to do this, and works perfectly fine. But, I feel like there is an other way of doing this in much easier way.

Finally from to dataframe that I need wrapping up above explanation:

From:

```
+-------------+---------+
|    col_a    |  col_b  |
+-------------+---------+
| row1a       | row1b   |
| row2a       | row2b   |
| row3a       | row3b   |
| row4a       | row4b   |
| row5a       | row5b   |
| row6a       | row6b   |
| row7a       | row7b   |
| ..          | ..      |
+-------------+---------+
```

To:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                    items                  |
+-------------------------------------------+
| [{"col_a": "row1a", "col_b": "row1b"},    |
|  {"col_a": "row2a", "col_b": "row2b"},    |
|  {"col_a": "row3a", "col_b": "row3b"},    |
|  {"col_a": "row4a", "col_b": "row4b"},    |
|  {"col_a": "row5a", "col_b": "row5b"}]    |
| [{"col_a": "row6a", "col_b": "row6b"},    |
|  {"col_a": "row7a", "col_b": "row7b"},...]|
| ..                                        |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

PS: I dont want to use df.collect()

Comment: Not sure but i guess you are looking for something like [Window fucntion](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window)

Comment: I've tried to find if I can use Window function, but, looks like its not helpful for my use case. Thanks